# Draw bitmaps from resources over another

Tags: android, bitmap, draw, android-canvas

I have got two bitmaps, *background* and *foreground*. How do I draw bitmap foreground on background without using another Canvas?

Solution:

1) First create bitmaps from resources with additional option ARGB_8888

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();  
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
```

2) Declare bitmaps

```
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background, options);  
Bitmap foreground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.foreground, options);
```

3) Inside onDraw() function draw graphics

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)    
{  
    canvas.drawColor(Color.White);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode( new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER));
    canvas.drawBitmap(foreground, 0, 0, paint); 
}
```

And as Soxxeh said, this is very good source of information: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Xfermodes.html

Comment: So does this solution work, or were you asking a question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImageBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(foregroundImageBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
```

The second image (foreground image) has to have Alpha aspects or you can't see through it.

Comment: How to set in Android these Alpha aspects of foreground bitmap?

Comment: When you create the Bitmap, give it an RGBA_8888 parameter, then draw to it as normal (do not set a background color). See [Bitmap.Config](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html). [This example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Xfermodes.html) may also give you some ideas.

Comment: Why are you supplying `null` instead of Paint instance?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky You don't need to specify a paint when drawing a bitmap. It's an optional argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an ImageView you can set the first bitmap as a background and the second as an image source.

```
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:src="@drawable/foreground"/>
```

Comment: What if not using an ImageView?

Comment: - On FrameLayout you can specify a foreground via setForeground().
- You can also use LayerDrawable to put multiple drawables on top of each other.
- Else just go with Eric's approach.