# Png file and bitmap

Tags: android, view, background, bitmap, png

New here :D

I have problem with my application. :/
In my app i have a bitmap(size is equal to screen in my emulator 480x800). I am draw some circles and lines. Now i want to add  small(44x44) picture(.png). This picture should be in foreground and bit map as a background. (Bitmap have change when user touch the screen)

this green circles are drawing

```
c.drawCircle(xAxis, yAxis, PBEngine.fieldGreenRadius, paint);
```

i want replace it by my own picture.

i can't find solution :/
sorry for englins
hope you understand me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @njzk2 has stated you could use the Canvas Draw function. An example can be seen in [Draw smoothly scaled bitmaps on Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294102/draw-smoothly-scaled-bitmaps-on-canvas)

There is also an example question here [Draw bitmaps from resources over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963838/android-draw-bitmap-from-resources-over-another) regarding using bitmaps as foreground and background images.