# draw over a white bitmap another bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to draw over a white painted bitmap another bitmap with doodles, but the result is always white:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = mBitmap;
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
canvas.drawColor(0xffffffff);
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
myBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
```

How i can make white as background, and paintings as foreground in the picture?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963838/android-draw-bitmap-from-resources-over-another

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question for futur askers:

```
Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), mBitmap.getConfig());
Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), mBitmap.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
bmp2.eraseColor(0xffffffff);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, new Matrix(), null);
```

bmOverlay  is the final bitmap we want.